# vscode tasks - problemMatcher works sometimes yes, sometimes not

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks, vscode-problem-matcher

I'm trying to use the "problemMatcher" below to have VSCode start the debugging process as soon as the string...

```
SUCCESSFUL
OPERATION
```

... is displayed in the terminal output.

**PROBLEMMATCHER**

```
[...]
        {
            "label": "startWithAwsSam",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "bash startWithAwsSam.bash",
            "isBackground": true,
            "dependsOn": [
                "buildWithAwsSam"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": [
                {
                    "pattern": [
                        {
                            "regexp": "\\b\\B",
                            "file": 1,
                            "location": 2,
                            "message": 3
                        }
                    ],
                    "background": {
                        "activeOnStart": true,
                        "beginsPattern": "^.*SUCCESSFUL*",
                        "endsPattern": "^.*OPERATION*"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
[...]
```

**OUTPUT SAMPLE (terminal)**

```
pyenv shell some-app
 > ----------------------------------- 
    Make the http request!
 < ----------------------------------- 
SUCCESSFUL
OPERATION
You can now browse to the above endpoints to invoke your functions. You do not need to restart/reload SAM CLI while working on your functions, changes will be reflected instantly/automatically. If you used sam build before running local commands, you will need to re-run sam build for the changes to be picked up. You only need to restart SAM CLI if you update your AWS SAM template
2023-05-22 23:17:41 WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:3000
2023-05-22 23:17:41 Press CTRL+C to quit
Invoking some_app/api.getFAQ (python3.8)
Local image is up-to-date
Using local image: public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8-rapid-x86_64.

Mounting /home/eduardolac/some-app/.aws-sam/build/GetFAQLambda as /var/task:ro,delegated, inside runtime container
START RequestId: 4fe811c9-bd5c-43c2-86f0-e0fd7398219e Version: $LATES
```

**PROBLEM**

The presented problemMatcher works sometimes yes, sometimes not. Even though the evaluated output is always the same.

**QUESTION**

How to solve this problem?

**Thanks!**

**PLUS:** If it were possible to use a "problemMatcher" to match a string anywhere in an output, that would be perfect!